# VPD (Virtual private database) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I'm interested is there any implementation for Oracle's VPD (Virtual private database) in PostgreSQL?

What are the limitations and how it's configured and used in applications?

Answer (score 3):

The closest feature in PostgreSQL is Row Security, which was [added to PostgreSQL 9.5, per the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html).